# Is it possible to clear route values with RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to redirect to an action in the same controller, but lose the route values (in particular, the `id` value).  This is turning out to be surprisingly difficult.  I have routes configured like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Monitoring_controllerIdSpecified",
    "Monitoring/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    new { action = "Status" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Monitoring_default",
    "Monitoring/{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Events", action = "Index" }
);
```

... and an action method inside `EventsController` something like this:

```
public ActionResult Status(int id) {
    if (id > 1000) {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "ID too high.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = (int?)null });
    }

    // (code to display status)
}
```

If I then access something like `/Monitoring/Events/1001`, the `RedirectToAction` is indeed invoked, but I get redirected to `/Monitoring?id=1001` instead of just `/Monitoring`.  It seems to be matching the first route, `Monitoring_controllerIdSpecified`, even though that route has `id` as a mandatory route parameter and I told it to set `id` to null, and bizarrely turning `id` into a query string key.  In other words, it is not properly clearing/removing the `id` route value.  Setting `id` to an empty string in the `routeValues` object passed to `RedirectToAction` just gives the same effect as setting it to `null`.

Why is it doing this and how can I convince it not to match the first route because `id` has been completely removed from the route values?

Comment: have you tried removing the Id from the routevaluedictionary before redirecting?

Comment: You could also try `RedirectToRoute` instead of `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: @Slicksim Which `RouteValueDictionary` are you talking about?  Could you give a code example of what you mean?

Comment: before your redirect, do the following   RouteData.Values.Remove("id");

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @Slicksim I found that the answer is to remove the key from `RouteData.Values` rather than setting it to null:

```
public ActionResult Status(int id) {
    if (id > 1000) {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "ID too high.";
        RouteData.Values.Remove("id");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // (code to display status)
}
```

Comment: This also works for Razor Pages, just clear the route data values before redirecting in the PageModel code.